# Undefined variable when registering user - Laravel

Tags: php, html, authentication

I want to store the registered email from user so if he doesnt get verification link on email to use resend function to get another email. Iam not allowing users to login so i cant get their email as `Auth::$user->email`, i created the hidden input to store the email but i get this error:

> Undefined variable: user

**This is my register function:**

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = Account::create([
            'login' => $data['login'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'verifyToken'=> Str::random(40),
            'active' => (env('CONFIRM_EMAIL', true)) ? 0 : 1
        ]);
        $thisUser = Account::findOrFail($user->id);

        if(env('CONFIRM_EMAIL') == true){
            $this->sendEmail($thisUser);
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

**This is my resend function and html code to store the email:**

```
protected function resend(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Account::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if($user){
            $user->verifyToken = Str::random(40);
            $user->save();
            $this->sendEmail($user);
            return back()->with('user',$user)->with('success', 'A link has been sent to your email');
        }
    }
```

```
<form action=" {!! route('resendEmail') !!}" method="POST">
     @csrf
     <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}">
     <button class="btn btn-default db" type="submit" value="Submit">Resend Verification Link</button>
 </form>
```

The error is pointing at the hidden input with value $user->email while the register function works fine and creates user in database.

Comment: Don't you need to add the user in your `back()->with(....)` in the `else`-block as well? But you shouldn't return an error if the email wasn't found. You should just send back a message saying something like "If the email address was found, an email with will be sent". Otherwise people can use this as a lookup service to see if someone has an account or not.

Comment: Thats not the problem, my hidden value="{{ $user->email }}">, that user doesnt get defined

Comment: The code `{{$user->email}}` in your view expects there to be a `$user` object. If you don't pass it but only pass an error, then you will get the error you say you get, the `$user` variable being undefined. I might be wrong though, haven't used Laravel in years.

Comment: Ugh, that my mistake from previous code i had with input, user would input an email to resend verification link so i didnt want to be with input but i forgot to delete the error and success.

Comment: but still even without the "else" block, i get undefined variable user and the error is pointing to the `<input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}">`

Comment: So when do you get that error? When you load what view in which situation? I don't see you loading any views in your code. Your `create` just returns the user but where do you call that method? And is there really a reason for your `$thisUser`? Doesn't `$user` already contain the user you want?

Comment: i call the create method in my register.blade the user gets registered in the database works just fine, but after i hit register it should redirect me to verify.blade where the html code from above is set. And  after i hit register i cant access verify.blade because the $user in the hidden input is not defined